# What is the usage of include in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I searched a lot but didnt get a right answer, what is the difference between include and {{}} in helm.

ex :

```
metadata:
  name: {{ include "cluster-dev.fullname" . }}
```

here can't it be like this

```
metadata:
  name: {{ Values.nameOverride }}
```

Comment: It's not surprising that Helm templates can be confusing at first.  `{{ }}` is required around *any* template-processing directive.  The ugliness is rather unfortunate, it originates from golang templates.  It simply means 'this is some template-processing code' as opposed to literal (yaml) text.  `include` is a template-processing directive which tells helm to reference a template function defined elsewhere (usually `_helpers.tpl`).

Answer (score 9):

`include` is meant to be used with templates and not to simply output values.

According to the [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-include-function)

> To make it possible to include a template, and then perform an operation on that template’s output, Helm has a special include function:
>
> `{{ include "toYaml" $value | indent 2 }}`
>
> The above includes a template called `toYaml,` passes it `$value`, and then passes the output of that template to the `indent` function.

Comment: my very bad ! am just started my legs in helm, can you please elaborate more ? pls ..

Comment: What's confusing is Helm's wording. They say you're including a template, but you're including a function there not a template. But you can also include a template too.

Comment: @JithinKumarS In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59575498/what-is-the-usage-of-include-in-helm#comment113211581_59575498), `{{ .Values.nameOverride }}` is how you can access data from values.yaml (or other *.yaml or --set) where `{{ include "cluster-dev.fullname" . }}` is coming from `_helpers.tpl` where you want this `fullname` to be X in condition A and Y in condition B or further processing `template` action can be used instead of `include` function
More on `include` vs `template` [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function)

Comment: So the `_helpers.tpl` is an implicit default template that will always be included?

Comment: @JithinKumarS this should be the answer as it describes it perfectly